# Miniconda3 Linux Python 3.7 64-Bit, Installer missing?

Tags: python, installation, conda, x86-64, miniconda

I was about to install miniconda when I realised that there is no installer for Python 3.7 and 64-Bit architecture for Linux available on the [conda-readthedoc](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) (see below).

[screenshot of miniconda linux installers available on condo.io](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkPoo.png)

Is there a reason I do not understand (such as that I could go with the 64-Bit installer for Python 3.8 and `conda install python 3.7` in an environment?)

**Edit:**
I believe there is just no Python 3.8 based installer for the 32-Bit miniconda version while the latest installer for 64-Bit is based on Python 3.8. (see comment in the [conda-docs](https://github.com/conda/conda-docs/tree/master/docs/source), refrencing `miniconda.rst.jinja2`, where any edits should be done before regenerating the site using the script `create_miniconda_rst.py`)
[see screenshot of miniconda.rst.jinja2 description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJI3X.png)

Anyway, it is not necessary for me (at this point) to go with the py37 based installer, as I can just create environments with earlier versions of python, even though my installer is 3.8. (in theory, I hope this works for my project).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why the 64-bit version is not listed, but the pages with the hashes mentions that version. And the repo page (https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/) links to the corresponding installer script as well.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I downloaded directly from the repo.

Then I looked into updating the readthedocs on github and as I was looking into the code that generates the readthedoc content, I realized that it is (fingers crossed) not relevant for me to use the 3.7 installer, as I can generate environments with earlier versions of Python anyway.